# Is there a way to use jQuery to animate separate svg elements to work in IE?

Tags: internet-explorer, animation, svg

I recently learned that Internet Explorer will **not** display CSS3 animations for individual separate SVG parts based on another Stack overflow response. If I were to select the general svg tag then it will work in IE but not for separate parts.

To show up in Internet Explorer, I can't seem to **only animate the dotted line border** of this SVG but **keep the icon in the center fixed and to not** animate.

Is there a way to allow the hover target area to be the entire SVG to start the rotation animation of the border but disable the animation in the center of the svg? Or do I need to layer the svg a certain way?

I'm trying to use conditional statements in jQuery to hopefully to get the animation to work in IE.

```js
/*Pseudo-code for jQuery solution. */

$('svg').mouseover(function() {
            if (!$(this).hasClass('dotted-line')) { //If it does not have the class .dotted-line
                $('g').rotate({ animateTo: false}); //Then disable animation
            } else if ($(this).hasClass('dotted-line')) { //If it does have .dotted-line class
                $('.dotted-line').animate({ rotate: '180deg' }, 1000); //then Rotate it
            }
        }); */
```

```css
/* This does not work in IE. What is the jQuery way to do this animation to work in IE */

svg {
   width: 40%;
   display: block;
   margin: 0 auto;
}

ellipse {
  pointer-events: all;
}
    ellipse:hover {
        width: 40%;
   display: block;
   margin: 0 auto;
            -webkit-animation-name: rotate;
            -webkit-animation-duration: 2s;
            -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
            -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
            -moz-animation-name: rotate;
            -moz-animation-duration: 2s;
            -moz-animation-iteration-count: 1;
            -moz-animation-timing-function: linear;
            animation-name: rotate;
            animation-duration: 2s;
            animation-iteration-count: 1;
            animation-timing-function: linear;
        }

        @-webkit-keyframes rotate {
            from {-webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);}
            to {-webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);}
        }

        @-moz-keyframes rotate {
            from {-moz-transform: rotate(0deg);}
            to {-moz-transform: rotate(360deg);}
        }

        @keyframes rotate {
            from {transform: rotate(0deg);}
            to {transform: rotate(360deg);}
        }

}
```

```html
<svg id="panda-circ" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 108.6182 107.5305">
  <title>panda-rotate</title>
  <g id="panda">
    <path d="M33.83,73.7l5.46-11.0852L53.0219,50.5369l17.8688-1.9853,14.394,6.4525,1.489-1.1582,4.7981-1.1582,3.3091,2.1509L98.19,52.1916l5.2943-.3308,4.3016,2.978L107.62,59.306s7.7761,6.9488,7.7761,7.1142,2.6474,5.7908,2.6474,5.7908l.6617,4.3016L124,79.16l-4.9635,9.7613-8.2723,3.971-10.2581.8271,2.1509,2.9783L94.7155,98.683,81.4794,95.87,62.6181,98.5175l-4.1362.3308S41.4405,96.0358,41.4405,95.87s-8.1072-9.7616-8.1072-10.0924S33.83,74.1965,33.83,73.7Z" transform="translate(-20.6909 -21.2348)" style="fill: none;stroke: #000"/>
    <path d="M34.6879,73.6446l9.8782-4.0771,4.6025,1.1981,2.9181,8.5791a19.851,19.851,0,0,1-.311,3.101c-.1644.0045-4.1244,5.5747-4.1244,5.5747L58.6493,98.4777l5.1005-.8018,3.3061-7.3731,1.6624-8.3209-1.6376-3.431s-5.7551-.8356-5.9191-.9966a70.2706,70.2706,0,0,0-7.92,3.7625" transform="translate(-20.6909 -21.2348)" style="fill: none;stroke: #000"/>
    <path d="M58.5861,98.6832S56.9139,91.9725,56.9139,91.8,59.65,85.09,59.8026,85.09s5.1289-3.2827,5.1289-3.2827l3.233,2.9385L67.1,91.6283l-3.1928,6.8828Z" transform="translate(-20.6909 -21.2348)" style="stroke: #000"/>
    <path d="M33.9952,73.7l10.2578-4.1362,5.6254,1.3236,6.9488,8.6034L52.36,82.6343l-4.1364,5.1292S59.64,98.3521,59.64,98.5175s-.9925.3308-.9925.3308L41.4405,95.705l-8.1072-9.5962Z" transform="translate(-20.6909 -21.2348)" style="stroke: #000"/>
    <path d="M37.47,66.0893a25.1522,25.1522,0,0,1-2.1509-1.9206,15.6168,15.6168,0,0,0,.6617-2.6588l3.971-3.693,2.6472,2.068s-2.6472,2.659-2.8128,2.659S37.8006,65.6462,37.47,66.0893Z" transform="translate(-20.6909 -21.2348)" style="stroke: #000"/>
    <path d="M44.0877,58.3811l.3185,11.3573,5.3988,2.638,3.217-21.84-8.297,19.5565" transform="translate(-20.6909 -21.2348)" style="fill: none;stroke: #000"/>
    <path d="M70.8645,48.7171s-20.9863,22.17-20.9863,22.3358,21.84,5.7908,21.84,5.7908Z" transform="translate(-20.6909 -21.2348)" style="fill: none;stroke: #000"/>
    <path d="M84.7885,54.7323Z" transform="translate(-20.6909 -21.2348)" style="fill: none;stroke: #000"/>
    <path d="M85.45,55.17l1.6547-1.3236,4.6324-1.1582,3.3091,1.9855-2.4818,3.8053L87.27,60.4642l-2.6472-1.82Z" transform="translate(-20.6909 -21.2348)" style="stroke: #000"/>
    <path d="M95.2117,54.5079s2.8126-2.3163,2.9783-2.3163,4.9635-.3308,4.9635-.3308l4.7978,3.1434-.3308,4.6327Z" transform="translate(-20.6909 -21.2348)" style="stroke: #000"/>
    <path d="M86.4429,66.9757" transform="translate(-20.6909 -21.2348)" style="fill: none;stroke: #000"/>
    <path d="M70.8907,48.7171l.6617,27.63,1.489,13.2361L81.6448,95.87l13.4015,2.978s7.7761-1.82,7.7761-2.1507a23.3375,23.3375,0,0,0-2.3163-2.9783s-6.7833-9.5959-6.9488-9.5959-9.2653-5.1292-9.2653-5.1292Z" transform="translate(-20.6909 -21.2348)" style="stroke: #000"/>
    <path d="M83.9611,51.0924" transform="translate(-20.6909 -21.2348)" style="fill: none;stroke: #000"/>
    <path d="M85.2847,55.0042,80.652,72.5419" transform="translate(-20.6909 -21.2348)" style="fill: none;stroke: #000"/>
    <path d="M107.7859,59.4714,93.5573,84.2889" transform="translate(-20.6909 -21.2348)" style="fill: none;stroke: #000"/>
    <path d="M93.7227,84.2889l8.2726-8.1072,9.5959-3.3088,3.64-6.6182" transform="translate(-20.6909 -21.2348)" style="fill: none;stroke: #000"/>
    <path d="M102.1607,75.8509l9.4305-3.1437,3.1437,6.4528-2.6472,4.1362L105.47,85.778s-3.64-3.3091-3.64-3.8053S102.3261,75.6855,102.1607,75.8509Z" transform="translate(-20.6909 -21.2348)" style="stroke: #000"/>
    <path d="M111.5912,72.8729l6.4528-.4965" transform="translate(-20.6909 -21.2348)" style="fill: none;stroke: #000"/>
    <path d="M124,79.3254l-2.978.9927,1.3236,1.6544Z" transform="translate(-20.6909 -21.2348)" style="stroke: #000"/>
  </g>
  <g transform="translate(54.3091,53.7653)">
  <ellipse id="dotted-line" rx="53.8091" ry="53.2652" style="fill: none;stroke: #2717ff;stroke-dasharray: 4.018310070037842,4.018310070037842"/>
</g>
</svg>
```

I'm thinking about using GSAP if I can't do it this way.

Comment: Please fix your code snippet. It doesn't run (missing jQuery).

Comment: It's pseudo JS code. I'll hide the jQuery for someone to fix and just put the css3 animation for now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK it is not that straightforward to have continuously running animations on hover with jQuery. Its `animate()` function is designed to animate a CSS value from a to b, and if you want to stop and restart it on hover, and have it resume again at the same speed, it starts to get complicated very quickly.

IMO, it is a lot simpler to implement this in plain Javascript.

```js
var animationRunning = false;
var pandaCirc = document.getElementById("panda-circ");
var dottedLine = document.getElementById("dotted-line");
var ellipseCircumference = 336;
var dashOffset = 0;
var dashOffsetDelta = 0.5;

pandaCirc.addEventListener("mouseenter", function() {
  animationRunning = true;
  requestAnimationFrame(animLoop);
});


pandaCirc.addEventListener("mouseleave", function() {
  animationRunning = false;
});


function animLoop(time) {
  dashOffset = (dashOffset + dashOffsetDelta) % ellipseCircumference;
  dottedLine.style.strokeDashoffset = dashOffset;

  if (animationRunning)
    requestAnimationFrame(animLoop);
}
```

```css
svg {
   width: 40%;
   display: block;
   margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<svg id="panda-circ" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 108.6182 107.5305">
  <title>panda-rotate</title>
  <g id="panda">
    <path d="M33.83,73.7l5.46-11.0852L53.0219,50.5369l17.8688-1.9853,14.394,6.4525,1.489-1.1582,4.7981-1.1582,3.3091,2.1509L98.19,52.1916l5.2943-.3308,4.3016,2.978L107.62,59.306s7.7761,6.9488,7.7761,7.1142,2.6474,5.7908,2.6474,5.7908l.6617,4.3016L124,79.16l-4.9635,9.7613-8.2723,3.971-10.2581.8271,2.1509,2.9783L94.7155,98.683,81.4794,95.87,62.6181,98.5175l-4.1362.3308S41.4405,96.0358,41.4405,95.87s-8.1072-9.7616-8.1072-10.0924S33.83,74.1965,33.83,73.7Z" transform="translate(-20.6909 -21.2348)" style="fill: none;stroke: #000"/>
    <path d="M34.6879,73.6446l9.8782-4.0771,4.6025,1.1981,2.9181,8.5791a19.851,19.851,0,0,1-.311,3.101c-.1644.0045-4.1244,5.5747-4.1244,5.5747L58.6493,98.4777l5.1005-.8018,3.3061-7.3731,1.6624-8.3209-1.6376-3.431s-5.7551-.8356-5.9191-.9966a70.2706,70.2706,0,0,0-7.92,3.7625" transform="translate(-20.6909 -21.2348)" style="fill: none;stroke: #000"/>
    <path d="M58.5861,98.6832S56.9139,91.9725,56.9139,91.8,59.65,85.09,59.8026,85.09s5.1289-3.2827,5.1289-3.2827l3.233,2.9385L67.1,91.6283l-3.1928,6.8828Z" transform="translate(-20.6909 -21.2348)" style="stroke: #000"/>
    <path d="M33.9952,73.7l10.2578-4.1362,5.6254,1.3236,6.9488,8.6034L52.36,82.6343l-4.1364,5.1292S59.64,98.3521,59.64,98.5175s-.9925.3308-.9925.3308L41.4405,95.705l-8.1072-9.5962Z" transform="translate(-20.6909 -21.2348)" style="stroke: #000"/>
    <path d="M37.47,66.0893a25.1522,25.1522,0,0,1-2.1509-1.9206,15.6168,15.6168,0,0,0,.6617-2.6588l3.971-3.693,2.6472,2.068s-2.6472,2.659-2.8128,2.659S37.8006,65.6462,37.47,66.0893Z" transform="translate(-20.6909 -21.2348)" style="stroke: #000"/>
    <path d="M44.0877,58.3811l.3185,11.3573,5.3988,2.638,3.217-21.84-8.297,19.5565" transform="translate(-20.6909 -21.2348)" style="fill: none;stroke: #000"/>
    <path d="M70.8645,48.7171s-20.9863,22.17-20.9863,22.3358,21.84,5.7908,21.84,5.7908Z" transform="translate(-20.6909 -21.2348)" style="fill: none;stroke: #000"/>
    <path d="M84.7885,54.7323Z" transform="translate(-20.6909 -21.2348)" style="fill: none;stroke: #000"/>
    <path d="M85.45,55.17l1.6547-1.3236,4.6324-1.1582,3.3091,1.9855-2.4818,3.8053L87.27,60.4642l-2.6472-1.82Z" transform="translate(-20.6909 -21.2348)" style="stroke: #000"/>
    <path d="M95.2117,54.5079s2.8126-2.3163,2.9783-2.3163,4.9635-.3308,4.9635-.3308l4.7978,3.1434-.3308,4.6327Z" transform="translate(-20.6909 -21.2348)" style="stroke: #000"/>
    <path d="M86.4429,66.9757" transform="translate(-20.6909 -21.2348)" style="fill: none;stroke: #000"/>
    <path d="M70.8907,48.7171l.6617,27.63,1.489,13.2361L81.6448,95.87l13.4015,2.978s7.7761-1.82,7.7761-2.1507a23.3375,23.3375,0,0,0-2.3163-2.9783s-6.7833-9.5959-6.9488-9.5959-9.2653-5.1292-9.2653-5.1292Z" transform="translate(-20.6909 -21.2348)" style="stroke: #000"/>
    <path d="M83.9611,51.0924" transform="translate(-20.6909 -21.2348)" style="fill: none;stroke: #000"/>
    <path d="M85.2847,55.0042,80.652,72.5419" transform="translate(-20.6909 -21.2348)" style="fill: none;stroke: #000"/>
    <path d="M107.7859,59.4714,93.5573,84.2889" transform="translate(-20.6909 -21.2348)" style="fill: none;stroke: #000"/>
    <path d="M93.7227,84.2889l8.2726-8.1072,9.5959-3.3088,3.64-6.6182" transform="translate(-20.6909 -21.2348)" style="fill: none;stroke: #000"/>
    <path d="M102.1607,75.8509l9.4305-3.1437,3.1437,6.4528-2.6472,4.1362L105.47,85.778s-3.64-3.3091-3.64-3.8053S102.3261,75.6855,102.1607,75.8509Z" transform="translate(-20.6909 -21.2348)" style="stroke: #000"/>
    <path d="M111.5912,72.8729l6.4528-.4965" transform="translate(-20.6909 -21.2348)" style="fill: none;stroke: #000"/>
    <path d="M124,79.3254l-2.978.9927,1.3236,1.6544Z" transform="translate(-20.6909 -21.2348)" style="stroke: #000"/>
  </g>
  <g transform="translate(54.3091,53.7653)">
  <ellipse id="dotted-line" rx="53.8091" ry="53.2652" style="fill: none;stroke: #2717ff;stroke-dasharray: 4.018310070037842,4.018310070037842"/>
</g>
</svg>
```

**Update: handling multiple animated icons**

The previous solution was a simplified version that supported only one icon.

If you need to have several icons being animated, then using global variables for offset is a bad idea.

Instead, we should just keep track of which icon is being animated, and read the dash offset directly from that element's state.

```js
var currentDottedLineBeingAnimated = null;
var currentAnimationFrameRequest = 0;
var dashOffsetDelta = 0.5;

// Need to use querySelectAll() to get ll the matching elements
var allIcons = document.querySelectorAll(".svgicons");
// Loop through all the matches and add mouse enter and leave event handlers
allIcons.forEach(function (icon) {

  icon.addEventListener("mouseenter", function (evt) {
    // Cancel any pending requestAnimationFrame() requests
    cancelAnimationFrame(currentAnimationFrameRequest);
    // New dotted line to be animated
    currentDottedLineBeingAnimated = evt.target.querySelector(".dotted-line");
    // Start the animation running by requesting an animation callback
    currentAnimationFrameRequest = requestAnimationFrame(animLoop);
  });

  icon.addEventListener("mouseleave", function () {
    // Stop animation by clearing the current amnimation element
    currentDottedLineBeingAnimated = null;
  });
  
});


function animLoop(time) {
  // If nothing is being animated, don't do anything this animation step
  if (!currentDottedLineBeingAnimated)
    return;
  // Read the element's dash offset and increment it by a little
  var dashOffset = Number(currentDottedLineBeingAnimated.style.strokeDashoffset) + dashOffsetDelta;
  currentDottedLineBeingAnimated.style.strokeDashoffset = dashOffset;
  // Request another animation callback
  currentAnimationFrameRequest = requestAnimationFrame(animLoop);
}
```

```css
svg {
  width: 30%;
  display: inline;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<svg class="svgicons" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 108.6182 107.5305">
  <title>panda-rotate</title>
  <g id="panda">
    <path d="M33.83,73.7l5.46-11.0852L53.0219,50.5369l17.8688-1.9853,14.394,6.4525,1.489-1.1582,4.7981-1.1582,3.3091,2.1509L98.19,52.1916l5.2943-.3308,4.3016,2.978L107.62,59.306s7.7761,6.9488,7.7761,7.1142,2.6474,5.7908,2.6474,5.7908l.6617,4.3016L124,79.16l-4.9635,9.7613-8.2723,3.971-10.2581.8271,2.1509,2.9783L94.7155,98.683,81.4794,95.87,62.6181,98.5175l-4.1362.3308S41.4405,96.0358,41.4405,95.87s-8.1072-9.7616-8.1072-10.0924S33.83,74.1965,33.83,73.7Z" transform="translate(-20.6909 -21.2348)" style="fill: none;stroke: #000"/>
    <path d="M34.6879,73.6446l9.8782-4.0771,4.6025,1.1981,2.9181,8.5791a19.851,19.851,0,0,1-.311,3.101c-.1644.0045-4.1244,5.5747-4.1244,5.5747L58.6493,98.4777l5.1005-.8018,3.3061-7.3731,1.6624-8.3209-1.6376-3.431s-5.7551-.8356-5.9191-.9966a70.2706,70.2706,0,0,0-7.92,3.7625" transform="translate(-20.6909 -21.2348)" style="fill: none;stroke: #000"/>
    <path d="M58.5861,98.6832S56.9139,91.9725,56.9139,91.8,59.65,85.09,59.8026,85.09s5.1289-3.2827,5.1289-3.2827l3.233,2.9385L67.1,91.6283l-3.1928,6.8828Z" transform="translate(-20.6909 -21.2348)" style="stroke: #000"/>
    <path d="M33.9952,73.7l10.2578-4.1362,5.6254,1.3236,6.9488,8.6034L52.36,82.6343l-4.1364,5.1292S59.64,98.3521,59.64,98.5175s-.9925.3308-.9925.3308L41.4405,95.705l-8.1072-9.5962Z" transform="translate(-20.6909 -21.2348)" style="stroke: #000"/>
    <path d="M37.47,66.0893a25.1522,25.1522,0,0,1-2.1509-1.9206,15.6168,15.6168,0,0,0,.6617-2.6588l3.971-3.693,2.6472,2.068s-2.6472,2.659-2.8128,2.659S37.8006,65.6462,37.47,66.0893Z" transform="translate(-20.6909 -21.2348)" style="stroke: #000"/>
    <path d="M44.0877,58.3811l.3185,11.3573,5.3988,2.638,3.217-21.84-8.297,19.5565" transform="translate(-20.6909 -21.2348)" style="fill: none;stroke: #000"/>
    <path d="M70.8645,48.7171s-20.9863,22.17-20.9863,22.3358,21.84,5.7908,21.84,5.7908Z" transform="translate(-20.6909 -21.2348)" style="fill: none;stroke: #000"/>
    <path d="M84.7885,54.7323Z" transform="translate(-20.6909 -21.2348)" style="fill: none;stroke: #000"/>
    <path d="M85.45,55.17l1.6547-1.3236,4.6324-1.1582,3.3091,1.9855-2.4818,3.8053L87.27,60.4642l-2.6472-1.82Z" transform="translate(-20.6909 -21.2348)" style="stroke: #000"/>
    <path d="M95.2117,54.5079s2.8126-2.3163,2.9783-2.3163,4.9635-.3308,4.9635-.3308l4.7978,3.1434-.3308,4.6327Z" transform="translate(-20.6909 -21.2348)" style="stroke: #000"/>
    <path d="M86.4429,66.9757" transform="translate(-20.6909 -21.2348)" style="fill: none;stroke: #000"/>
    <path d="M70.8907,48.7171l.6617,27.63,1.489,13.2361L81.6448,95.87l13.4015,2.978s7.7761-1.82,7.7761-2.1507a23.3375,23.3375,0,0,0-2.3163-2.9783s-6.7833-9.5959-6.9488-9.5959-9.2653-5.1292-9.2653-5.1292Z" transform="translate(-20.6909 -21.2348)" style="stroke: #000"/>
    <path d="M83.9611,51.0924" transform="translate(-20.6909 -21.2348)" style="fill: none;stroke: #000"/>
    <path d="M85.2847,55.0042,80.652,72.5419" transform="translate(-20.6909 -21.2348)" style="fill: none;stroke: #000"/>
    <path d="M107.7859,59.4714,93.5573,84.2889" transform="translate(-20.6909 -21.2348)" style="fill: none;stroke: #000"/>
    <path d="M93.7227,84.2889l8.2726-8.1072,9.5959-3.3088,3.64-6.6182" transform="translate(-20.6909 -21.2348)" style="fill: none;stroke: #000"/>
    <path d="M102.1607,75.8509l9.4305-3.1437,3.1437,6.4528-2.6472,4.1362L105.47,85.778s-3.64-3.3091-3.64-3.8053S102.3261,75.6855,102.1607,75.8509Z" transform="translate(-20.6909 -21.2348)" style="stroke: #000"/>
    <path d="M111.5912,72.8729l6.4528-.4965" transform="translate(-20.6909 -21.2348)" style="fill: none;stroke: #000"/>
    <path d="M124,79.3254l-2.978.9927,1.3236,1.6544Z" transform="translate(-20.6909 -21.2348)" style="stroke: #000"/>
  </g>
  <g transform="translate(54.3091,53.7653)">
  <ellipse class="dotted-line" rx="53.8091" ry="53.2652" style="fill: none;stroke: #2717ff;stroke-dasharray: 4.018310070037842,4.018310070037842"/>
</g>
</svg>
 
<!---Second SVG-->

          <svg class="svgicons" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 108.6182 107.5305"> 
 
 <path id="provider-wholeicon" d="M107.0568,55.6591h-3.58V52.08a1.1926,1.1926,0,0,0-1.1932-1.1932H69.6126l-.8635-1.7269A1.193,1.193,0,0,0,67.6818,48.5H49.7841a1.1929,1.1929,0,0,0-1.1932,1.1932v1.1932H42.625A1.1929,1.1929,0,0,0,41.4318,52.08V96.2273A4.7778,4.7778,0,0,0,46.2045,101h57.2727a4.7774,4.7774,0,0,0,4.7727-4.7727V56.8523A1.1926,1.1926,0,0,0,107.0568,55.6591ZM48.5909,96.2273a2.3864,2.3864,0,0,1-4.7727,0V53.2715h4.7727Zm52.5-42.9557v2.3876H71.999l-1.1932-2.3876Zm4.7727,42.9557a2.39,2.39,0,0,1-2.3864,2.3864H50.337a4.7459,4.7459,0,0,0,.64-2.3864V50.8852H66.9442l3.25,6.5008a1.19,1.19,0,0,0,1.0673.6583h34.6023Z" transform="translate(-20.6909 -21.2348)" style="fill: #0088ce;stroke: #fff;stroke-miterlimit: 10;stroke-width: 0.5px"/> 
 <ellipse class="dotted-line" cx="54.3091" cy="53.7653" rx="53.8091" ry="53.2652" style="fill: none;stroke: #0088ce;stroke-dasharray: 4.018310070037842,4.018310070037842"/> 
 </svg>
```

Comment: Hi Paul, I can't figure out how to apply your code to work on a group of svg icons all with the same class. I tried using querySelectorAll but the console said your pandaCirc.addEventListener code wasn't a function.

Please see for HELP:
https://codepen.io/CurlyLeeLee/pen/BdJjPE

Comment: Thank you Paul for your recent response. ES6 foreach is awesome! Unfortunately, my job doesn't use Babeljs to compile ES6 now. I will keep this as a learning note.

Comment: It is easy enough to switch to a plain for loop. Or add a [polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach#Polyfill) for it.